# Resolving IP Address from hostname with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the ipaddress from a hostname using Powershell, but I really can't figure out how.

Any help?

Comment: Not having a windows machine I can't be sure, but isn't either nslookup or dig available?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can get all the IP addresses with [GetHostAddresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses) like this:

```
$ips = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("yourhosthere")
```

You can iterate over them like so:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("yourhosthere") | foreach {echo $_.IPAddressToString }
```

A server may have more than one IP, so this will return an array of IPs.

Comment: $ip = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("yourhosthere")[0] will ensure you get only one IP address if you are sure it resolves

Answer (score 40):

this is nice and simple and gets all the nodes.

```
$ip = Resolve-DNSName google.com
$ip
```

also try inputting an ip instead of a domain name and check out those results too!

Comment: Under the hood how does this differ to [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses?

Comment: If you want to access just the IP address using this method, use $ip.IPAddress.  Note this will return an array if there are multiple IPs.

Comment: `Resolve-DnsName` isn't part of PowerShell Core / PowerShell 7, so for cross platform you'll want `System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses`.

Comment: unlike `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("yourhosthere")`, this shows result with a small delay (somewhat like a second in my case)

Comment: @Castrohenge quite interestingly `Resolve-DNSName` successfully pulls the IP in cases where it is set to [`SkipAsSource`](https://cordero.me/microsoft-windows-server-2016-with-multiple-ips-assigned-to-a-single-interface/) (for instance specified in `hosts`) where `GetHostAddresses()` fails

Answer (score 20):

Use [Resolve-DnsName](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590781(v=wps.630).aspx) cmdlet.

```
Resolve-DnsName computername | FT Name, IPAddress -HideTableHeaders | Out-File -Append c:\filename.txt
```

---

```
PS C:\> Resolve-DnsName stackoverflow.com

Name                                           Type   TTL   Section    IPAddress
----                                           ----   ---   -------    ---------
stackoverflow.com                              A      130   Answer     151.101.65.69
stackoverflow.com                              A      130   Answer     151.101.129.69
stackoverflow.com                              A      130   Answer     151.101.193.69
stackoverflow.com                              A      130   Answer     151.101.1.69

PS C:\> Resolve-DnsName stackoverflow.com | Format-Table Name, IPAddress -HideTableHeaders

stackoverflow.com 151.101.65.69
stackoverflow.com 151.101.1.69
stackoverflow.com 151.101.193.69
stackoverflow.com 151.101.129.69
```

---

```
PS C:\> Resolve-DnsName -Type A google.com

Name                                           Type   TTL   Section    IPAddress
----                                           ----   ---   -------    ---------
google.com                                     A      16    Answer     216.58.193.78


PS C:\> Resolve-DnsName -Type AAAA google.com

Name                                           Type   TTL   Section    IPAddress
----                                           ----   ---   -------    ---------
google.com                                     AAAA   223   Answer     2607:f8b0:400e:c04::64
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 11):

You could use vcsjones's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8660947), but this might cause problems with further ping/tracert commands, since the result is an array of addresses and you need only one.

To select the proper address, [`Send`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.send) an ICMP echo request and read the [`Address`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply.address) property of the echo reply:

```
$ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
$ip = $($ping.Send("yourhosthere").Address).IPAddressToString
```

Though the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply.address#remarks) from the documentation say:

> The [`Address`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply.address) returned by any of the [`Send`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.send) overloads can originate from a malicious remote computer. Do not connect to the remote computer using this address. Use DNS to determine the IP address of the machine to which you want to connect.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave, apparently my habit of using parentheses to group an item is over excessive here.  This next updated line gets you the same result,  without the extra $(...):

$ips = $ping.Send("yourhosthere").Address.IPAddressToString

Thanks for asking.  Less is more...

Comment: This works well on WIndows, but when running Powershell 7.0.3 on Ubuntu, the record returned was effectively empty and reported an IP address of 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Doesn't look like you can control whether you get a v6 or v4 address.

Answer (score 4):

Working one liner if you want a single result from the collection:

```
$ipAddy = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("yahoo.com")[0].IPAddressToString;
```

hth

Comment: I can confirm that this method works in both Powershell and Powershell 7.0.3 running on Ubuntu 20.04, and it seems to be a LOT faster than ll the other methods I've tested.

Answer (score 2):

If you know part of the subnet (i.e. 10.3 in this example), then this will grab any addresses that are in the given subnet:

```
PS C:\> [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("MyPC") | foreach { $_.IPAddressToString | findstr "10.3."}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked well for my purpose

```
$ping = ping -4 $env:COMPUTERNAME
$ip = $ping.Item(2)
$ip = $ip.Substring(11,11)
```

Comment: This method didn't work in Powershell 7.0.3 running on Ubuntu 20.04, it just hangs before it gets any responses.

Answer (score 1):

```
$computername = $env:computername    
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($computername)  | where {$_.AddressFamily -notlike "InterNetworkV6"} | foreach {echo $_.IPAddressToString }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

The Test-Connection command seems to be a useful alternative, and it can either provide either a Win32_PingStatus object, or a boolean value.

Documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code if you have a bunch of hosts in text file

```
$a = get-content "C:\Users\host.txt"(file path) 

foreach ($i in $a )
    {
$i + "`n" + "==========================";[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($i) 

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way:

```
ping hostname
```

e.g.

```
ping dynlab938.meng.auth.gr
```

it will print:
   Pinging dynlab938.meng.auth.gr [155.207.29.38] with 32 bytes of data

Comment: as the question is for powershell I would expect the answer to be a string/object containing the ip address

Answer (score -1):

try
$address = 'HOST NAME'

Resolve-DnsName $address | Select-Object Name, IPAddress | Export-csv "C:\Temp\CompleteNSLookup.csv" -append -NoType

Comment: how is this different from the other Answer that uses the same cmdlet?